# Deep Query using MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, database

I tried to find something like this:

```
{
    "request": {
    "item": [
        NumberLong(392279374),
        NumberLong(392238484),
        NumberLong(392222298),
        NumberLong(392154783),
        NumberLong(392154349),
        NumberLong(392109059),
        NumberLong(392093297),
        NumberLong(392079037),
        NumberLong(391209132),
        NumberLong(390465588)
    ]
    }
}
```

How can I query "NumberLong(392154349)" ?
Thanks.

Comment: `request.item[index of wanted value]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well, answer is simple as hell**

```
db.item.finsSomething({"request.item":{$in:[number]}})
```

Comment: Please explain the code that you've presented as an answer.  Simply posting code is unlikely to adequately answer the asker's question.

Comment: do you have personal project as a part time job ?  Ruby/Rails

Answer (score 0):

First you should aggregate your data and then find your criteria below aggregation will help 
mongo document structure as

```
db.item.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5469f1cbeb2d08494b4bff1e"),
    "request" : {
        "item" : [
            NumberLong(392279374),
            NumberLong(392238484),
            NumberLong(392222298),
            NumberLong(392154783),
            NumberLong(392154349),
            NumberLong(392109059),
            NumberLong(392093297),
            NumberLong(392079037),
            NumberLong(391209132),
            NumberLong(390465588)
        ]
    }
}
```

and the aggregation query as

```
db.item.aggregate({"$unwind":"$request.item"},
           {"$match":{"request.item":NumberLong(392154349)}})
```

Comment: Well, i have "Uncaught Exception":

aggregate failed: { "errmsg" : "Exception: $unwind: value at end of field path must be an array"

Comment: is your structure   `   "request": {"item": [ ` like request inside array item then it work properly if not then please edit your question with proper document formatt

Comment: Can you provide complete query ? Probably made something wrong.

Comment: Still, dunno what i need to type in MongoDB query field ? 
db.item.findOne() **or** db.collectionName.aggregate() ?

Comment: first you insert mongo as db.item.insert({"request" : {
        "item" : [
            NumberLong(392279374),
            NumberLong(392238484),
            NumberLong(392222298),
            NumberLong(392154783),
            NumberLong(392154349),
            NumberLong(392109059),
            NumberLong(392093297),
            NumberLong(392079037),
            NumberLong(391209132),
            NumberLong(390465588)
        ]
    }}) then db.item.findOne() after that used db.item.aggregate() query above query